# Append each line of a text as a element of a nested list

Tags: python

I've got a txt file that I want to read and append to a list.

[image: source_file]

This is what I have so far of my code:

```
for line in open(filename):
  items = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')   # strip new-line characters and split on column delimiter
  items = [item.strip() for item in items]  # strip extra whitespace off data items
  F.append(items)
```

So far so good. The issue here is that I want each line to be appended to a list with the following structure:

```
F = [(4,3050),(1,4000),]
```

How do I make it read the file to append to that specific structure?

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, you're now getting a list of lists, and you want a list of tuples; is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Firstly, be sure you are using tabulations in your text file. According to your screenshot, it seems that your are using a space.

Secondly, to store a tuple rather than a list in your list `F` use `F.append(tuple(items))`.

### Final code

```py
F = []
for line in open(filename):
  items = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
  items = [item.strip() for item in items]
  F.append(tuple(items))  # Add tuple() here
print(F)
```

### Output

`[('4', '3050'), ('1', '4000')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csp_test.txt', sep=" ", header = None)
list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

If you want a one liner,

```
import pandas as pd
list(pd.read_csv('csp_test.txt', sep=" ", header = None).itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Either way, you will get the following output,

```
[(4, 3050), (1, 4000)]
```

This way, you don't have to worry about splitting your fields or performing any strip operations.